# Calculate total cost based on rate and duration like Hours,Minutes with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdown list to present the duration of a specific job with the format "hours,minutes":

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option></option>
    <option>0,10</option>
    <option>0,20</option>
    <option>0,30</option>
    <option>0,40</option>
    <option>0,50</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>1,10</option>
    <option>1,20</option>
    <option>1,30</option>
    <option>1,40</option>
    <option>1,50</option>
</select>
```

I have the rate hour:

```
var rate = "8"; // 8 €
```

If the user selects for example "1,3", how can I calculate the total cost based on the rate? (in this case the total would be 12€)

Comment: It's really unclear what _exactly_ you're asking for. This code won't work anyway, as your `select` doesn't have a name, so it won't be posted. Parsing a decimal is trivial, multiplying two numbers also is. Please read [ask] and improve your question. Share your research and explain what help specifically you're looking for.

Comment: Hi, I think the question is simple to understand.

Comment: I'm not saying your end goal isn't clear, I'm saying that it's unclear with what part specifically you need help. Your question as-is is _"Please write the code for me"_, which is not how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: @CodeCaster sorry but I don't agree with you, the question is not based on a submit/code process problem, but based on a pure c# calculation

Comment: You tagged the question asp.net-mvc and included a block of HTML. If this is solely about C#, I'll redirect you to [ask] again, especially [mcve]. It is unclear whether your question is _"How to convert a string in the format of `h[,mm]` to a decimal"_, or _"How to multiply two numbers"_, and you don't show any research nor effort.

Comment: @CodeCaster you can't say I did not research or did not made an effort before I asked the question, because I did. The issue is that I had no ideia what would be the best format for the formula (string or decimal) or if I would need to use the TimeSpan function.

Comment: You clearly still didn't read [ask]. Your research does not show from your question.

Comment: Because all I found was based on Excel formulas and nothing related with C#, so I had no ideia what would be the direction to take, and now I know thanks to @Nikhil

Comment: Because you can't convert an Excel formula to mathematical representation, or even its representation in words, add that to your question and ask _"How to write this in C#"_? I'm really trying to help you improve your question, but if you don't want to, nevermind.

Comment: Sorry but I think it's clear what the question is, but I thank you for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
string[] time  = "1,30".Split(",");

int total = Convert.ToInt32(time[0]) * rate;

if (time.Length >1)
    total += Convert.ToInt32(time[1]) * rate / 60;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. Is there any formula without the need of spliting the value in hours and minutes?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal Ok, Maybe I can build a function that take the string with the duration and rate, and get back with the total

Comment: @CodeCaster: Thanks.